# Receiving the error "The provided site url can't be set as a Home site" when setting a home site in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, homepage

In SharePoint Online, I am using SharePoint online management shell to set a home site. My code is this

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/home-site

```
$orgName="myorg"
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com

Set-SPOHomeSite -HomeSiteUrl "https://myorg.sharepoint.com"
```

However I get

```
Set-SPOHomeSite : [Error ID: 09149788-0a26-4cee-a333-699b81f629d7] The provided site url can't be set as a Home site. Check aka.ms/homesites for 
cmdlet requirements.
At C:\set_home_site.ps1:6 char:1
+ Set-SPOHomeSite -HomeSiteUrl "https://myorg.sharepoint.com"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOHomeSite], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPOHomeSite+SetSPHSite
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you are trying to run the script against a Team site.

Only communication sites can become home sites. [Quote](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spohomesite?view=sharepoint-ps#description):

> Use this cmdlet to set a SharePoint Site as a Home Site. A home site
> is a **communication** site that you create and set as the top landing
> page for all users in your intranet. For more information, see Set up
> a home site for your organization

Comment: Oh ok, I will check that. Also I'm a bit confused but does the link need to be in the format of `https://myorg.sharepoint.com` or `https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite`?

Comment: Also how would I confirm if my site is a team site?

Comment: You can tell if a site a communication site by the lack of the left navigation. Chances are your site has the left nav. https://sharepointmaven.com/what-is-a-communication-site-in-sharepoint-and-why-you-might-need-one/

Comment: Actually my site does not have the left navigation.

Comment: Both URLsare correct: https://myorg.sharepoint.com or https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite But it's also two different URLs for two totally different sites. As long as the site you target is a Communication site your script should work

Comment: Can you insert the screenshot of the site you are targeting?

Comment: Probably not as it has a lot of company details on it unfortunately. It does look similar to this though https://sharegate.com/app/uploads/2017/07/full-screen-communication-site.png. Is it possible it was made a team site but then customized to look like this?

Comment: Is there a commandlet that can tell if its a team or communication site.

Comment: Yes, simply use `$site = Get-SPOSite -id https://myorg.sharepoint.com"` and then `$site.Template`

Comment: ok that command gave me `SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0`. Is this not a communication site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118606/discussion-between-denis-molodtsov-and-omega).